# Escape Characters in Linux Not Working

Tags: c++, c, linux, text-files

Say I want to print a string with quotes around it, ( "example" ).

In Linux, doing the same thing works in the simplest case. However, is there some reason in Linux that doing this will generate a new line at the end of the command? For instance, running my program in Windows:

```
std::cout<<"Blah \""<<example<<"\" Blah";
```

In Linux I have however

```
Blah " 
example" Blah
```

Is there any reason why this should be happening? (Why am I getting this newline?)

Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure that `example` doesn't just start with a newline character?

Comment: Your examples don't seem to be escaped correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The way you are doing is wrong.

```
"Blah "\" << example << "\"Blah";
```

The above is wrong. `"Blah "\"` have closing double quotes before the backslashed double quotes.

This should work.

```
std::cout<<"Blah \""<<example<<"\" Blah";
```

Comment: The OP had 'example' as an identifier (likely a string), so I think this may be more what they're looking for:   std::cout << "Blah \"" << example << "\" Blah";

Comment: Ok, I missed that part. Updated.